# Edit HTML blogger and blogpost content disappeared

Tags: html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8NPD.png)

I edit HTML blogger with read more option. Everything went great but after 3-4 hours blog post content disappeared. Where is the problem?

Content can be seen fully on homepage, on clicking link it shows the same as I uploaded the image. Blog link: www.modonika.com.

Comment: First, tell me, what you did to add read more option?

Comment: I have removed the coding for read more now. Done all this steps from this link: http://helplogger.blogspot.in/2012/03/auto-read-more-with-thumbnail-for.html
Now revert all changes.

Comment: Done as you said but no change... :(
Should I revert it as before 
itemprop="description articleBody"

Comment: Wait a minute. I think found the error.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Do as directed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go To Blogger> Template> Edit HTML>

Search this-

```
itemprop='articleBody'>
```

Now copy following code after that line (At next line).

```
<data:post.body/>
```

Your code should be as shown in the image.

[image]

Comment: **Thank you so much** Akshay. :)
Its all back. Credit to you.

Comment: Suggest me should I post that "read more" option on homepage with the same code on: http://helplogger.blogspot.in/2012/03/auto-read-more-with-thumbnail-for.html
Don't want full blogpost on homepage. 
Please advise with the code tutorial.

Comment: And If you think I solved your issue, please choose this as answer by pressing the button 'select As Answer button' at the left of this answer.

Comment: Kz.. got it. Done.
With the same code present here: http://helplogger.blogspot.in/2012/03/auto-read-more-with-thumbnail-for.html